# How to set & get value of pointer Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

In Objetive-C when I want set/change value of pointer. I use

```
*pointer = value
```

But In Swift, how to get/set value of pointer?

I'm woking with bitmap pixel:

```
  NSUInteger offsetPixelCountForInput = ghostOrigin.y * inputWidth + ghostOrigin.x;
  for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < ghostSize.height; j++) {
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < ghostSize.width; i++) {
      UInt32 * inputPixel = inputPixels + j * inputWidth + i + offsetPixelCountForInput;
      UInt32 inputColor = *inputPixel;

      newR = MAX(0,MIN(255, newR));
      newG = MAX(0,MIN(255, newG));
      newB = MAX(0,MIN(255, newB));

        *inputPixel = RGBAMake(newR, newG, newB, A(inputColor));
    }
  }
```

So I want to convert this code into Swift, but I'm stuck with pointers.

**23.03.2016 - Update code**

```
var inputPixels:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32> = nil
inputPixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(calloc(inputHeight * inputWidth, UInt(sizeof(UInt32))))
```

Comment: There are no pointers in swift.

Comment: see here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html
and this  https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can work with pointers in Swift. There are `UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer` generic types.

Here is a function that takes a `float` pointer
You can use float variable and pass it's address `&floatVar`
or you can create and allocate an `UnsafeMutablePointer` and pass it. But you have to manually allocate and deallocate memory.

When you work with an `UnsafeMutablePointer` pointer type and want to assign some value to it you have to do the following:

- check if points to some variable (not nil)
- Assign your value to the `memory` property

**Code Example:**

```
func work (p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>) {
    if p != nil {
      p.memory = 10
    }
    println(p)
    println(p.memory)
  }

var f: Float = 0.0
var fPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> = UnsafeMutablePointer.alloc(1)

work(&f)
work(fPointer)
fPointer.dealloc(1)
```

Comment: But bear in mind that you may not want to do that, depending on *why* you want a pointer. In your example, it looks like you're using pointer arithmetic to calculate the index into a one-dimensional array from two-dimensional coordinates. In Swift (as in Objective C) you could just calculate the array index you need (e.g. `index = j * inputWidth + i + offsetPixelCountForInput`) and use square bracket syntax to access the value, e.g. `inputPixels[index]`. We'd need to see the rest of your code (e.g. declaration of inputPixels) to give the best advice.

Comment: Just a a note: Using UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> you can also store the pointer in a variable.

Comment: @KostiantynKoval Thank you sir for your invaluable help.

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help you, thanks @AlessandroOrnano :)

Comment: Swift3 version: func work (_ p: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>) {
    if p != nil {
        p.pointee = 10
    }
    print(p)
    print(p.pointee)
}

var f: Float = 0.0
work(&f)
f
var fPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> = UnsafeMutablePointer.allocate(capacity: 1)
work(fPointer)
fPointer.deallocate(capacity: 1)

Answer (score 46):

You should use **pointee** property instead of **memory** in Swift 3

```
pointer.pointee = value
```

Comment: What about arrays?

Comment: In swift 4, I am getting error **Cannot assign to property: 'pointee' is a get-only property**. How it is working?

Comment: @dahiya_boy make sure to use a mutable version - UnsafeMutablePointer